# LinkedList Delete End in C

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I am trying to program a simple text editor in C and I am using LinkedList. I  have problems with the deleteEnd function. Where did I go wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
```

i store the character, and the coordinates of the character in a structure like this:

```
struct node {
    struct node *previous;
    char c;
    int x;
    int y;
    struct node *next;
}*head;
```

This is called whenever a letter is typed in.

```
void characters(char typed, int xpos, int ypos)     //assign values of a node
{
    struct node *temp,*var,*temp2;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->c=typed;
    temp->x=xpos;
    temp->y=ypos;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        temp2=head;
        while(temp2!=NULL)
        {
            var=temp2;
            temp2=temp2->next;
        }
        temp2=temp;
        var->next=temp2;
        temp2->next=NULL;
    }
}
```

Print the new node if there are changes.

```
void printer()          //to print everything
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        gotoxy(temp->x,temp->y);
        printf("%c",temp->c);
        temp=temp->next;
    }

}
```

Now here, I do not know why the last element of the head won't be deleted.

```
void deletesEnd()
{
    struct node *temp,*last;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        last=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(last->previous== NULL)
    {
        free(temp);
        head=NULL;
    }
    last=NULL;
    temp->previous=last;
    free(temp);
}
```

**This is where it all begins.**

```
main()
{
    char c;         //for storing the character
    int x,y;        //for the position of the character
    clrscr();
    for(;;)
    {
        c=getch();
        x=wherex();
        y=wherey();
        if(c==0x1b)     //escape for exit
        {
            exit(0);
        }

        else if (c==8)  //for backspace
        {
            deletesEnd();
            // clrscr();
            printer();
        }

        else            //normal characters
        {
            characters(c,x,y);
            printer();
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: You have a `previous` link, but you never set in when inserting new nodes.

Comment: I am still working on the deleteFunction then insertion would be next and then delete in the middle of a linked list. I am taking it slowly, I am new at this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
void deletesEnd()
{
struct node *temp,*last;
temp=head;
last = temp;
while(temp != NULL && temp->next!=NULL)
{
    last=temp;
    temp=temp->next;
}
if(last == temp)
{
    free(temp);
    head=NULL;
} else {
    free(last->next);
    last->next = NULL;
}
```

In your algorithm, you try to work with a NULL pointer, so you can't get to the previous node I think.

Comment: This works just great. But I am still confused which part I worked with a NULL pointer. I am sorry if it sounds dumb, I am really a beginner at linkedList.

Comment: When you loop like this : while(temp!=NULL) , you'll stop when you reach a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

For finding the last node in the list, the simplest is to loop until the `next` pointer is `NULL`.

For deletion at the end you also need to keep track of the next-to-last node, and it could look something like this:

```
struct node *prev, *curr;

for (prev = NULL, curr = head; curr->next != NULL; prev = curr, curr = curr->next)
    ;

/* `curr` is now the last node in the list, `prev` is the next-to-last node */
if (prev != NULL)
    prev->next = NULL;  /* Unlink the last node */
else
    head = NULL;  /* List was only one node long */

/* Free the memory for the last node */
free(curr);
```

---

If you properly kept the list double-linked the loop would be even easier, as you don't have to keep track of the next-to-last node anymore:

```
struct node *node;

for (node = head; node->next != NULL; node = node->next)
    ;

/* `node` is now the last node in the list */
if (node->previous != NULL)
    node->previous->next = NULL;  /* Unlink last node */
else
    head = NULL;  /* List was only one node long */

/* Free the memory for the last node */
free(curr);
```

---

And keeping track of the tail from the start will make this *much* simpler:

```
if (tail != NULL)
{
    struct node *node = tail;

    if (node->previous != NULL)
    {
        node->previous->next = NULL;  /* Unlink last node */
        tail = node->previous;
    }
    else
        head = tail = NULL;  /* Removing last node in list */

    free(node);
}
```

Comment: I tried double link, but everything went into shambles. So I thought I should understand the single link first before I can ever understand the double. I am new at this taking things slowly :D

Comment: @user2624491 Even with a single link list, having a pointer to the tail is useful, especially if you only insert at the end like you do. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
void deletesEnd()
{
   struct node *temp,*last;
   temp=head;

   while(temp!=NULL)
   {
       last=temp;
       temp=temp->next;
   }

   if(last->previous== NULL)
   {
        free(temp);
        head=NULL;
   }

   last->previous->next = NULL;
   last=NULL;
   temp->previous=last;
   free(temp);
}
```

you see, you've put the last element in the list in `last`, and then did `last=NULL;` which just put null in `last` variable. `temp` is already `NULL` so `temp->previous=last;` has no meaning.
you need that the last item's previous item will point to `NULL` as the line

```
last->previous->next = NULL;
```

does

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```
temp->previous=last;
```

will cause you problems since temp is null at that point already (since it was the termination condition in the while loop).

Change your method to :

```
void deletesEnd()
{
   struct node *temp,*last;
   temp=head;
   while(temp!=NULL)
   {
       last=temp;
       temp=temp->next;
   }
   if(last != NULL) {
       if (last->previous != null) { // Last element gonig to be deleted so the previous element if exists should point his next to null (end of list)       
           last->previous->next = null;
       }   
       free(last); // Free the last element in the list
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linkedlist work with only two simple generic rules...

1. First Make the link
2. Second after make, Break the link.

Just check the condition...

1. If you have empty list
2. if list has only one node
3. if it has more then one node

try these rules. I hope it will work for you.